# Duda entre try-catch y throws

Tags: java, eclipse, try-catch

Cuando escribo .start() en el codigo para indicar que empiece el proceso, el programa Eclipse me da un error y me da dos opciones: envolver dicho .start() en un bloque try-catch o añadir un throws a la clase. Cual es la diferencia entre usar un bloque try-catch para envolver un codigo y poner un throws en la clase?

Comment: la pregunta esta genérica pero un `try catch` sirve para indicarle al sistema que intente realizar dicha acción y de no lograrlo, retorne el error generado por ejemplo, en php sería `try{ //algo de codigo }catch(Exception $e){ echo $e->getMessage(); }` mientras que el throw sirve para generar una excepción si no se ejecuta una acción, ejemplo: `if(!$a){ throw new Exception ("mensaje de la excepcion"); }` lo que detendría la ejecución del codigo si esta conbinada con el try catch

Comment: El try catch captura las excepciones y en el bloque catch debes decidir que hacer si suceden. Throws levanta la excepción hacia el metodo que invocó dicho fragmento de cogio.  Te recomiendo que leas: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/

Comment: Supón que con el bloque try/catch capturas la exception y haces con esta lo que quieras, ya sea enviar mensajes de error, o cerrar la conexión de una base de datos, o lo que sea. Con el throws, lo que haces es que cuando suceda un error, simplemente lo rechazas, no las toma en cuenta. Si sucede un error en una linea, ahí termina la ejecución de ese método, y ya continua ejecutando las demás lineas de abajo,

Answer (score 3):

Un método solo puede lanzar una *checked exception* si está declarada con la cláusula *throws*. De esta forma, un código que use este método sabe que es posible que se lance la excepción durante la llamada al mismo.

Así pues, si `metodoA` llama a `metodoB` y `metodoB` tiene, p.ej. `throws FileNotFoundException`, el compilador sabe que hay dos opciones:

- `metodoA` no trata la posible excepción. Cuando `metodoB` lance la excepción, a su vez `metodoA` propagará la excepción hacia el método que lo invoco. Por lo tanto, por lo dicho arriba, `metodoA` puede lanzar la excepción así que necesita declararla en su `throws`.
- La llamada a `metodoB` está dentro de un `try/catch` que captura la excepción definida en el `throws` y no la vuelve a lanzar. Como no hay riesgo de que `metodoA` lance la excepción, no necesita declararla en su cláusula `throws`.